# Confusion with Nokogiri::XML::Text#text output

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I wrote the code below:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'pp'

html = <<-END
<html>

    <head>

    <title> A Dirge </title>

    <link rel     = "schema.DC"
          href    = "http://purl.org/DC/elements/1.0/">

    <meta name    = "DC.Title"
          content = "A Dirge">

    <meta name    = "DC.Creator"
          content = "Shelley, Percy Bysshe">

    <meta name    = "DC.Type"
          content = "poem">

    <meta name    = "DC.Date"
          content = "1820">

    <meta name    = "DC.Format"
          content = "text/html">

    <meta name    = "DC.Language"
          content = "en">

    </head>

    <body><pre>

            Rough wind, that moanest loud
              Grief too sad for song;
            Wild wind, when sullen cloud
              Knells all the night long;
            Sad storm, whose tears are vain,
            Bare woods, whose branches strain,
            Deep caves and dreary main, -
              Wail, for the world's wrong!

    </pre></body>

    </html>
 END

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html)
pp doc 
doc.children.each do |ch|
    p ch.text if ch.text?
end
```

But it outputs:

```
"\n\n    \n\n    "
"\n\n    "
```

Now my question is why does the line inside `<pre>`..`<\pre>`not printed?

Can any one help me to fix that issue?

Comment: In a question, reduce your input data to the minimum needed to adequately reproduce a problem. In this case, none of the `<head>` block is pertinent. Retaining the `<title>` is OK, but don't bother with the `<meta>` tags, which needlessly clutter things.

Answer (score 1):

The `doc.children.each` block outputs a bit more than that for me:

```
"\n\n    \n\n    "
"\n\n    "
"\n\n    "
"\n\n    "
"\n\n    "
"\n\n    "
"\n\n    "
"\n\n    "
"\n\n    \n\n    "
"\n\n    \n"
```

That's correct output; those are the text nodes that are direct children of `<html>`.

I'm not sure which "line" you wanted that you're not seeing.  If, for example, you want the contents of the `<pre>`, you could do

```
doc.xpath("pre").text
```

to get it.  If that doesn't answer things for you, you'll have to clarify your question.